# Visual Studio: Unable to run project with large resource

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a strange issue when running my project. I added a file in my resources which is `1.8GB`, I set the file type as `Binary`. Building the project won't give me an issue, but when I tried to run it says:
[image]

I also notice that the designer has thrown an error of `OutMemoryException`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 - Enterprise.

Comment: You probably shouldn't do that, especially if the resource gets embedded into the .exe.

Comment: Why is that? We need that file in our project. It is one of the main file of the project. Any suggestion?

Comment: Well, is the file's Build Action "Embedded Resource" or similar? With a file of that size, it sounds like a bad idea. You can just set it to be copied to the output folder (how, I forget), and then read it from there.

Comment: I see. We need to embed the file in a single exe.

Comment: Why is that a requirement, if I may ask? There _are_ ways to embed data in .exes that aren't resources (this is what e.g. self-extracting ZIPs do), but you'll then need custom reading code for the data.

Comment: Actually, the file is a zip, then later after running the app, it will extract into `Temp` directory, after using the app all the required files will be deleted. Can you suggest any alternative method? We're building a portable app, and we need a single exe for that.

Comment: So you program extract 1.8 gb of data on the disk to delete it after. Sounds like that file is a database of some sort and it's not the way to do things anyhow

Comment: I use this to wrap all my files into one exe file: - https://enigmaprotector.com/en/aboutvb.html

Comment: Two files ("MyApp.exe" and "Data.zip") is still a portable app in my books.

Comment: A 1.8GB file is definitely not a resource.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this is run as a x86/32-bit application. Now one rule is that these files are not allowed to be larger then 4 GiB. Wich is the maximum memory you can adress under x32.

Now there is another issue with .NET Applications. Actually on x32 it faces a way lower [memory limit of 2 GiB](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases). With compiler switches that can be bumped to 3 GiB and even 4 GiB on a x64 OS.

Note that regardless of that, any *single object* in memory is not allowed to be bigger then 2 GiB. Of course for such a size, it might also be hard to find any space in memory with Fragmentation.

That .zip File is 1.8 GiB. When loading a file into memory, usually all compression as to be undone. So I not thing this likely to work.

Aside from self-executing Archives (wich usually had autosplit on), I only saw a big file integrated into the .exe **once** that I can remember in 35 years. It was the installer for the Game Sword of the Stars, on the DVD. It was a stupid idea, because then the Vista UAC came around. And the Vista UAC will scan the *entire file* before it even shows that prompt. So there was a massive delay between trying to execute and even getting teh "this needs elevation prompt. .exe are not really *expected* to be anywhere that size. Even if they fixed the UAC or that is solved by the Manifest, it is still a bad idea.